# WooCommerce rest API cannot save HTML that uses youtube embed iframe in description field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

On a stock wordpress (version 5.7) + woo commerce (version 5.1.0) install with no other plugins  the youtube iframe embed gets stripped out of my html for description of product when creating via API.

Here is code:

```
<?php
require 'wooapi/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;


$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://localhost/wordpress/',
    'ck_44b92c00ea35e6cc59c89c29051bf67c22e0df3a', 
    'cs_dd833592a1ef7a00a82c1711fd455db2e4c5bd15',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2',
    ]
);


$woocommerce->post('products', array('name' => 'YOUTUBE HTML','description' => '<h1>Before YouTube Video</h1><iframe width="1172" height="659" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AEMGOEccLAk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe><h2>After Video</h2>'));
```

What actual gets saved to product

```
<h1>Before YouTube Video</h1><h2>After Video</h2>
```

NOTE that if I use the GUI to put in the html it works fine. The issue only seems to be API. I have tried v2 and v3 and they both do NOT allow this.

How can I get this to work?